# Puppeteer - Scraping FiveThirtyEight Presidential Approval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I saw one other SO question, but it had no answers, and was from 2018. Am I supposed to intercept XHR? JSON Get requests? Any help getting started here appreciated.

I try to scrape by selector or xpath, and it always times out saying the xpath doesn't exist. I've tried various functions to wait until the page is well and truly loaded, no dice. Something funky seems to be occurring for puppeteer that it doesn't actually load the page, whereas for me, as a real human, it well and fully loads, and I see an element with the approval rating.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's in an iframe, here is the src: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-approval-ratings/promo.html

You can get those with:

```
document.querySelector('.approve .val').innerHTML
// "42.6"
document.querySelector('.disapprove .val').innerHTML
// "52.7"
```

Comment: /html/body/div/a/div/svg[1]/g/text[2]/tspan[1] is the xpath on that /promo URL, but I still get a timeout error still in my scraper. How did you find that it's in an iframe? I don't see that iframe on the page source for the base URL.

Comment: I managed to scrape the value with a css scraping method, still can't get it with xpath scraping method.

Comment: In chrome right click on it and go to "inspect". It will show you where it is in the DOM.

Comment: Yes. After you click inspect, right-click the element, and copy xpath. It has a valid xpath. For some reason, the xpath isn't selectable for scraping.